# Two way SSL authentication issue: HTTP 500 - Terminated Hadshake by peer | error writing in socket | PKCS12

Tags: java, spring-boot, ssl, ssl-certificate

Im with a strange problem with twao way SSL Auth.
My PKCS12 (.jks) file works fine with Postman, but, in my Java application I'm receiving a 500.

Here my code:

```java
package br.com.votorantim.vucl.base.infoconv;

import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory;
import org.apache.http.conn.ssl.TrustSelfSignedStrategy;
import org.apache.http.conn.ssl.TrustStrategy;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClients;
import org.apache.http.protocol.BasicHttpContext;
import org.apache.http.protocol.HttpContext;
import org.apache.http.ssl.SSLContextBuilder;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.http.client.HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory;
import org.springframework.util.ResourceUtils;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

import javax.net.ssl.KeyManagerFactory;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLSocket;
import javax.net.ssl.TrustManagerFactory;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.security.KeyStore;
import java.security.SecureRandom;
import java.security.cert.CertificateException;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;


@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String... args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    RestTemplate restTemplate() throws Exception {

        KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(ResourceUtils.getFile("classpath:infoconv01.jks"), "SENHA".toCharArray());
        keyStore.load(new FileInputStream(ResourceUtils.getFile("classpath:infoconv01.jks")),"SENHA".toCharArray());
        TrustStrategy acceptingTrustStrategy = (cert, authType) -> true;
        SSLContext sslContext = getContext();

        SSLConnectionSocketFactory socketFactory = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(sslContext);

       CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom().setSSLSocketFactory(socketFactory).build();
        HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory httpFactory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(httpClient);
        RestTemplate template = new RestTemplate(httpFactory);
        try {
            template.exchange("https://acesso.infoconv.receita.fazenda.gov.br/ws/cpfrest/api/ConsultaCpf/ConsultarCPFD3", HttpMethod.POST, null, String.class);

        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return template;
    }


    private SSLContext getContext() throws Exception {

        char[] keystorepass = "SENHA".toCharArray();

        try {
            KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");

            keyStore.load(new FileInputStream(ResourceUtils.getFile("classpath:infoconv01.jks")), keystorepass);

            KeyManagerFactory kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance(KeyManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
            kmf.init(keyStore, keystorepass);

            KeyStore trustStore = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");

            trustStore.load(new FileInputStream(ResourceUtils.getFile("classpath:cacerts")), "changeit".toCharArray());

            TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
            tmf.init(trustStore);

            SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
            sslContext.init(kmf.getKeyManagers(), tmf.getTrustManagers(), new SecureRandom());

            return sslContext;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new Exception("Erro ao criar contexto para SSLSocket!", e);
        }
    }
}
```

And here are my logs:

```
 {"timestamp":"2021-02-08 16:31:17.528-0300","level":"INFO","thread":"main","logger":"org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader","message":"Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 8690 ms","context":"default"}
    org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on POST request for "https://acesso.infoconv.receita.fazenda.gov.br/ws/cpfrest/api/ConsultaCpf/ConsultarCPFD3": Remote host terminated the handshake; nested exception is javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host terminated the handshake
            at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:751)
            at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:677)
            at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:586)
            at br.com.votorantim.vucl.base.infoconv.Application.restTemplate(Application.java:60)
            at br.com.votorantim.vucl.base.infoconv.Application$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$8e3c13e6.CGLIB$restTemplate$0(<generated>)
            at br.com.votorantim.vucl.base.infoconv.Application$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$8e3c13e6$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$ed7a4d98.invoke(<generated>)
            at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:244)
            at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:363)
            at br.com.votorantim.vucl.base.infoconv.Application$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$8e3c13e6.restTemplate(<generated>)
            at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
            at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
            at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
            at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:640)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:475)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1338)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1177)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:557)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1287)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1207)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:636)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:116)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:397)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1429)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:594)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1287)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1207)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:636)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:116)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:397)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1429)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:594)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
            at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:879)
            at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:878)
            at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550)
            at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141)
            at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:747)
            at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397)
            at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315)
            at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226)
            at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215)
            at br.com.votorantim.vucl.base.infoconv.Application.main(Application.java:38)
    Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Remote host terminated the handshake
            at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.handleEOF(SSLSocketImpl.java:1529)
            at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(SSLSocketImpl.java:1367)
            at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readHandshakeRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1268)
            at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:401)
            at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:373)
            at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.createLayeredSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:436)
            at org.apache.http.conn.ssl.SSLConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(SSLConnectionSocketFactory.java:384)
            at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:142)
            at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:374)
            at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:393)
            at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:236)
            at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:186)
            at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:89)
            at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110)
            at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185)
            at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83)
            at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:56)
            at org.springframework.http.client.HttpComponentsClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(HttpComponentsClientHttpRequest.java:87)
            at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.executeInternal(AbstractBufferingClientHttpRequest.java:48)
            at org.springframework.http.client.AbstractClientHttpRequest.execute(AbstractClientHttpRequest.java:53)
            at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:742)
            ... 59 more
            Suppressed: java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: socket write error
                    at java.base/java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
                    at java.base/java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:110)
                    at java.base/java.net.SocketOutputStream.write(SocketOutputStream.java:150)
                    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketOutputRecord.encodeAlert(SSLSocketOutputRecord.java:83)
                    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:384)
                    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.TransportContext.fatal(TransportContext.java:296)
                    at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:411)
                    ... 76 more
    Caused by: java.io.EOFException: SSL peer shut down incorrectly
            at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.read(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:481)
            at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.readFully(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:459)
            at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.decodeInputRecord(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:243)
            at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketInputRecord.decode(SSLSocketInputRecord.java:181)
            at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLTransport.decode(SSLTransport.java:110)
            at java.base/sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.decode(SSLSocketImpl.java:1359)
            ... 78 more
```

I'm stucked in it by 5 days!
Do you ever faced this problem? I tried several tutorials, and I'm always getting this problem.

Thanks!

Comment: Well, whenever possible, try to bring some reproducible scenario: but I would say you cannot share your keys, right? So, I will drop you some guessing: check server TLS version (nmap --script ssl-enum-ciphers -p 443 189.9.84.127) and maybe try to get your SSLContext this way "SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLSv1.2");". If it doesn't work, gimme some more data, like JDK/Spring version and if there's a way to reproduce it generating my own keys.

Comment: Hi @Reginaldo Santos!
I can't use nmap in firm pc.
I tried with TLSv1.1 and TLSv2.2, not worked
Thanks anyway! :)

Comment: Looks like it is a private service. Cannot do much but only blind guessing: 1. Are behind some company proxy? If so, try to add a HttpHost to your HttpClient mapping the proxy like here http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/examples/org/apache/http/examples/client/ClientExecuteProxy.java.

Comment: 2. I'm not too sure, but running from SB app, you're inside a HTTP web container and trying to do some HTTPS connection. So, try to use a CommandLineRunner instead just to move around this possibility: @Bean public CommandLineRunner run(RestTemplate restTemplate) throws Exception {return args ->{restTemplate.exchange( .... );};}

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have created all the objects correctly, but you didn't supplied the socketfactory to your http client. Can you retry with the following snippet:

```
CloseableHttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.custom()
    .setSSLSocketFactory(socketFactory)
    .build()

HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory httpFactory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(httpClient);
RestTemplate template = new RestTemplate(httpFactory);
```

Comment: I used this snippet before, but accidentaly deleted it :P
Not worked :(
Thank you anyway :)